# GPU parallel programming C/C++

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu

I want to learn gpu parallel programming in C/C++. What Library and compiler should I use. If they are opensource, that would be nice.
note: I have some practice with openmp and mpi. Though it is only for cpu parallel programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I depends on you GPU.

**OpenCL**

It is open source and works on Nvidia and AMD cards.

> https://www.khronos.org/opencl/

**CUDA**

Propriety NVidia solution for parallel programming. Optimized for their cards.

> http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html