# Fast color quantization in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

How can I reduce the number of distinct colors in images using OpenCV (+ C++) the fastest way possible? I don't want the complete code. I'm already doing it using kmeans but it's not very fast. This is the part of my code that is slow:

```
kmeans(samples, clusterCount, labels,
    TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 10, 10.0),
    1, KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS, centers);
```

This code takes a few seconds to process which is very very slow for me. I was using Matlab for this (`rgb2ind`) which was fast. Almost 0.01 seconds.

I want to use my code for production where the users expect the program to be fast.

Is there any alternative to kmeans for color quantization? Is there any way to run kmeans faster (which I don't think so because I've tried many different parameters)?

**Edit:**
Turned out color quantization is a very complex topic and takes time to write a good optimized one. I've decided to use `Magick++ (ImageMagick API)` for this.
Because of that I haven't tried Cris Luengo's new (edited) answer. But I mark it as answer (check out the comments too) so that other people don't think this question isn't answered.

Comment: Please provide a proper MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Note also that providing sample times with no indication of image size or content or your OS or machine spec is not very helpful.

Comment: If you want to use k-means to find the most relevant colors, apply it to the histogram rather than the pixels directly. A color histogram doesn't need more than 32 or 64 bins for each channel. If all you want to do is quantize, without optimizing colors, simply apply integer division to each channel.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm using the same machine and image for both Matlab and C++. But Matlab is >100x faster.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm not forced to only use k-means. It just seem the only option, unless you know a better one. Can you expand your answer please? What do you mean by optimizing colors and integer division to each channel? k-means gets the quantity by the number of each data in the input, not a number (like in histogram).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are many ways to quantize colors. Here I describe four.

## Uniform quantization

Here we are using a color map with uniformly distributed colors, whether they exist in the image or not. In MATLAB-speak you would write

```matlab
qimg = round(img*(N/255))*(255/N);
```

to quantize each channel into `N` levels (assuming the input is in the range [0,255]. You can also use `floor`, which is more suitable in some cases. This leads to `N^3` different colors. For example with `N=8` you get 512 unique RGB colors.

## K-means clustering

This is the "classical" method to generate an adaptive palette. Obviously it is going to be the most expensive. The OP is applying k-means on the collection of all pixels. Instead, k-means can be applied to the color histogram. The process is identical, but instead of 10 million data points (a typical image nowadays), you have only maybe 32^3 = 33 thousand. The quantization caused by the histogram with reduced number of bins has little effect here when dealing with natural photographs. If you are quantizing a graph, which has a limited set of colors, you don't need to do k-means clustering.

You do a single pass through all pixels to create the histogram. Next, you run the regular k-means clustering, but using the histogram bins. Each data point has a weight now also (the number of pixels within that bin), that you need to take into account. The step in the algorithm that determines the cluster centers is affected. You need to compute the weighted mean of the data points, instead of the regular mean.

The result is affected by the initialization.

## Octree quantization

An octree is a data structure for spatial indexing, where the volume is recursively divided into 8 sub-volumes by cutting each axis in half. The tree thus is formed of nodes with 8 children each. For color quantization, the RGB cube is represented by an octree, and the number of pixels per node is counted (this is equivalent to building a color histogram, and constructing an octree on top of that). Next, leaf nodes are removed until the desired number of them is left. Removing leaf nodes happens 8 at a time, such that a node one level up becomes a leaf. There are different strategies to pick which nodes to prune, but they typically revolve around pruning nodes with low pixel counts.

This is the method that Gimp uses.

Because the octree always splits nodes down the middle, it is not as flexible as k-means clustering or the next method.

## Minimum variance quantization

[MATLAB's `rgb2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html), which the OP mentions, does uniform quantization and something they call "minimum variance quantization":

> Minimum variance quantization cuts the RGB color cube into smaller boxes (not necessarily cubes) of different sizes, depending on how the colors are distributed in the image.

I'm not sure what this means. [This page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/reduce-the-number-of-colors-in-an-image.html#f8-13153) doesn't give away anything more, but it has a figure that looks like a k-d tree partitioning of the RGB cube. K-d trees are spatial indexing structures that divide spatial data in half recursively. At each level, you pick the dimension where there is most separation, and split along that dimension, leading to one additional leaf node. In contrast to octrees, the splitting can happen at an optimal location, it is not down the middle of the node.

The advantage of using a spatial indexing structure (either k-d trees or octrees) is that the color lookup is really fast. You start at the root, and make a binary decision based on either R, G or B value, until you reach a leaf node. There is no need to compute distances to each prototype cluster, as is the case of k-means.

**[Edit two weeks later]** I have been thinking about a possible implementation, and [came up with one](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/src/segmentation/minimum_variance_partitioning.cpp). This is the algorithm:

- The full color histogram is considered a partition. This will be the root for a k-d tree, which right now is also the leaf node because there are yet no other nodes.
- A priority queue is created. It contains all the leaf nodes of the k-d tree. The priority is given by the variance of the partition along one axis, minus the variances of the two halves if we were to split the partition along that axis. The split location is picked such that the variances of the two halves are minimal (using Otsu's algorithm). That is, the larger the priority, the more total variance we reduce by making the split. For each leaf node, we compute this value for each axis, and use the largest result.
- We process partitions on the queue until we have the desired number of partitions:

  - We split the partition with highest priority along the axis and at the location computed when determining the priority.
  - We compute the priority for each of the two halves, and put them on the queue.

This is a relatively simple algorithm when described this way, [the code](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/src/segmentation/minimum_variance_partitioning.cpp) is somewhat more complex, because I tried to make it efficient but generic.

## Comparison

On a 256x256x256 RGB histogram I got these timings comparing k-means clustering and this new algorithm:

| # clusters | kmeans (s) | minvar (s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3.98 | 0.34 |
| 20 | 17.9 | 0.48 |
| 50 | 220.8 | 0.59 |

Note that k-means needs more iterations as the number of clusters increases, hence the exponential time increase. Normally one would not use such a big histogram, I wanted to have large data to make the timings more robust.

Here is an example of these three methods applied to a test image:

Input:

[image: Input]

Uniform with `N=4` leading to up to 64 different colors [with `N=2` to get 8 different colors and comparable to the other methods, the result is very ugly]:

[image: Uniform]

K-means with 8 colors:

[image: K-means]

New "minimum variance" with 8 colors:

[image: New "minimum variance"]

I like this last result better than the K-means result, though they are fairly similar.

---

This program illustrates how to do color quantization using [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) and its implementation of the minimum variance partitioning:

```cpp
#include "diplib.h"
#include "dipviewer.h"
#include "diplib/simple_file_io.h"
#include "diplib/histogram.h"
#include "diplib/segmentation.h"
#include "diplib/lookup_table.h"

int main() {
   dip::Image input = dip::ImageRead( "/Users/cris/dip/images/flamingo.tif" );
   input.SetColorSpace( "RGB" ); // This image is linear RGB, not sRGB as assumed when reading RGB TIFFs.

   // Compute the color histogram.
   dip::Histogram hist( input, {}, { dip::Histogram::Configuration( 0.0, 255.0, 64 ) } );

   // Cluster the histogram, the output histogram has a label assigned to each bin.
   // Each label corresponds to one of the clusters.
   dip::uint nClusters = 8;
   dip::Image histImage = hist.GetImage(); // Copy with shared data
   dip::Image tmp;
   dip::CoordinateArray centers = dip::MinimumVariancePartitioning( histImage, tmp, nClusters );
   histImage.Copy( tmp ); // Copy 32-bit label image into 64-bit histogram image.

   // Find the cluster label for each pixel in the input image.
   dip::Image labels = hist.ReverseLookup( input );

   // The `centers` array contains histogram coordinates for each of the centers.
   // We need to convert these coordinates to RGB values by multiplying by 4 (=256/64).
   // `centers[ii]` corresponds to label `ii+1`.
   dip::Image lutImage( { nClusters + 1 }, 3, dip::DT_UINT8 );
   lutImage.At( 0 ) = 0; // label 0 doesn't exist
   for( dip::uint ii = 0; ii < nClusters; ++ii ) {
      lutImage.At( ii + 1 ) = { centers[ ii ][ 0 ] * 4, centers[ ii ][ 1 ] * 4, centers[ ii ][ 2 ] * 4 };
   }

   // Finally, we apply our look-up table mapping, painting each label in the image with
   // its corresponding RGB color.
   dip::LookupTable lut( lutImage );
   dip::Image output = lut.Apply( labels );
   output.SetColorSpace( "RGB" );

   // Display
   dip::viewer::ShowSimple( input, "input image" );
   dip::viewer::ShowSimple( output, "output image" );
   dip::viewer::Spin();
}
```

Comment: great answer, exactly what I was looking for, after trying out Kmeans and quantization. I would like to know if there's a python implementation. 
or @CrisLuengo 's code could be used without didplib itself.

Comment: @iratzhash: you can use DIPlib from within Python, there’s a wrapper for that. You can also take the relevant code and use only that. All that the license requires is acknowledgement.

Comment: Thank you so much for [the implementation](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/src/segmentation/minimum_variance_partitioning.cpp). Could you please show me some example code I can read and understand how to do what you did above? It would be very helpful. I’m quantizing an image and extracting the palette colors, which seems simple with your library, but having hard time actually making it work.

Comment: @КонстантинВан I've added C++ code with lots of comments to replicate the results in the answer. Replace `dip::MinimumVariancePartitioning` with `dip::KMeansClustering` for k-means clustering.

Comment: I was wondering if you could let me understand the algorithm more. **[Q Ⅰ]** Would the image gamma affect the quantization result ― Should I gamma-correct (linearize) a gamma-encoded (e. g. sRGB) image to properly perform the minimum variance quantization on? **[Q Ⅱ]** Would the image color space affect the quantization result ― Say, we have three _same-looking_ images of linear RGB, CIELAB, and CIEXYZ with known chromaticities; when performed the minimum variance quantization, would the result images _look_ different with each other (not taking precision differences into account)?

Comment: @КонстантинВан: Yes, I suspect that both the color space and gamma correction likely affect the results. On my blog I wrote [a post about this method](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/932) that might give a bit more insight. Look at the example with the dots. Each dot is a color. Gamma correction of the image would put some dots closer together and some further apart. This would affect the choice of optimal split.

Answer (score 13):

**[Fast pairwise nearest neighbor based algorithm](http://www.cs.joensuu.fi/sipu/pub/Threshold-JEI.pdf)** with 8 colors
High quality and fast
[image]

**[Efficient, Edge-Aware, Combined Color Quantization and Dithering](http://cg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/people/~huanghz/publications/TIP-2015-CombinedColorQuantization.pdf)** with 8 colors
Higher quality for 32 or less colors but slower
[image]

**[Spatial color quantization](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dcoetzee/downloads/scolorq/)** with 8 colors
Higher quality for 32 or less colors but the slowest
[image]

**[Sample c++ code](https://github.com/mcychan/nQuantCpp/tree/master/nQuantCpp)**
For the speed, it might be depending on [GPU parallel programming C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818090/gpu-parallel-programming-c-c).

Comment: Nice addition. These are mostly dithering methods, which make an image with quantized colors look much better. I hadn't seen the combined color quantization and dithering before. Thanks for pointing it out!