# What is the algorithm behind photoshop palette knife effect?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, colors, photoshop

I am trying to find the algorithm or even the general idea behind some of the effects used in Photoshop. Specifically, the **palette knife** effect that simplifies the colors of an image. For instance, the image bellow:

[image]

turns into something like this:

[image: p]

I want for each group of pixels that have similar color, to turn into a simple block of one or two colors (in real time) as happens in Photoshop. Any idea of a method to do this is appreciated.

Following tucuxi's suggestion, I could run a classification algorithm like **kNN** to pick **K** main colors for each image (frame in the video) and then change each pixel's color the the closest one from the **k** representatives. I am going to put the code here, and I appreciate any suggestions for improving it.

Comment: If you want to do as you describe, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710006/fast-color-quantization-in-opencv/49715101#49715101) for faster options. But note that this is not the algorithm that produced the images you show. It is some non-linear filter that is likely proprietary and not disclosed. It looks like it is related to the bilateral filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to choose representative colors, you can proceed as follows:

1. choose K colors from among N total present in the image
2. for each pixel in the image, replace it with its nearest color within the K chosen

To achieve step 1, you can run a [k-nearest-neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) over the actual color-space. In an WxH image, you have WxH pixels, each with a color. You choose K random colors to act as centroids, add the closest pixels to each, and after a while, you finish up with K different colors that more-or-less represent the most important colors of the image (in terms of being not too far from all others). Note that this is only one possible clustering algorithm - I am sure a lot of literature exists on alteratives and their relative merits.

Step 2 is comparatively much easier. For each original pixel, calculate distance to each of the K chosen colors, and replace it by the closest one.

Comment: thank you for the helpful response. I am trying to do what you said. However, Photoshop does this in real time as you can adjust the stroke size and see the changing results immediately. Do you think this method would work the same way on a normal CPU?