# Is there a way to get the most common items from an array and exclude double items?

Tags: c#, image-processing

For a project, I need to reduce the colors from an image from 24bit to 8bit.

I want to **create a function that could find the 256 most used colors in the image** so I can use these colors in a new color palette and do some color quantization on the image

I already have a function that can read the pixel colors from the image

```c
public static byte[] OwnGetColorData(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            int height = bmp.Height;
            int width = bmp.Width;
            int res = height * width;
            var colors = new List<List<byte>>();
            var pixelColor = new List<byte>();
            Color c;

            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Height; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y< bmp.Width; y++)
                {
                    c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

                    pixelColor.Add(c.R);
                    pixelColor.Add(c.G);
                    pixelColor.Add(c.B);

                    colors.Add(pixelColor);
                    pixelColor.Clear();
                }
            }
            return pixelColor.ToArray();
        }
```

the output of this function is a 2-dimensional array that has an RGB array on every pixel index. ex: on index 0 is pixel 1 with array(255, 255, 255)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast color quantization in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710006/fast-color-quantization-in-opencv)

Comment: well, it clearly shows what the outcome should be, but I can't use librarys so I'll have to loop over each pixel item.

Comment: It also gives names of algorithms that you can look up and implement.