# How to efficiently identify most dominant colour clusters in image with Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, cluster-analysis, k-means

Consider this image:

[image]

Six distinct colours can be seen here. But if we zoom in we see that border-smoothing increases the colour-count:

[image]

(NOTE: The image background is not guaranteed to be clean, but the least-dominant text-color will still dominate more than the most-noisy background-color).

I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm (< 5ms on a macbook, needs to run realtime) that will identify the 3 most dominant colours with a reasonable degree of accuracy.

I can see a potential recursive solution:

```
def extract_colors(im, mask=None):
    points = {sample a handful of points from image&mask}
    if not enough points:
        return []

    primary_color = estimate_primary_color_for(points)
    mask = mask | mask_close_to(im, primary_color)

    return primary_color + extract_colors(im, mask)
```

... but I can't see how to implement; the devil is in the details. And I want to be sure I am not reinventing a wheel before diving in.

Comment: What do you mean by "color clusters"? Do you mean the colors must come in clusters of pixels or something else? How about kmeans with k>3 --- pick some value such as 6 for example that is not too large. Then use the histogram to get the 3 most frequent colors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast color quantization in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710006/fast-color-quantization-in-opencv)

Comment: You need under 5ms for what size image?

Comment: @fmw42 I want to identify all secondary-dominant pixels and all tertiary-dominant pixels. In my example image, that would be the green ones and the grey ones. I'm wary of `kmeans` performance issues. However I think I may be able to use it over a sparse sample set...

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for putting that code in the public domain. While I need something that integrates into my Python codebase, it is helping me get traction on the task.

Comment: @MarkSetchell About 1200x800.

Comment: DIPlib is available from Python. Unless you think you need to reimplement everything yourself from scratch. Also, the code is open source with a liberal license, but not public domain; attribution is required.

Answer (score 2):

If your sample image is representative, and you are looking for saturated colours, you could convert to HSV colourspace, and threshold either the saturation or lighter colours. Then do a uniform quantisation of the saturated pixels in the Hue channel down to say 10 colours (Hue = (Hue//18) *18) and count frequencies of each of the 10 bins, something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(im):
    # OpenCV uses a range of 0..180 for Hue, rather than conventional 0..360
    bins = 18
    binWidth = 180//bins
    HSV = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    H, S, V = cv2.split(HSV)
    maskedV = V>50
    quantH  = ((H*maskedV)//binWidth)*binWidth
    res = np.histogram(quantH,bins=18,range=(0,180))
    return res

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('rqrny.png')

In [70]: process(im)
Out[70]: 
(array([241701,      0,   1944,     36,      0,      0,  11088,   4860,
             0,      0,   9672,  16878,     36,    180,    108,   2412,
             0,      0]),
 array([  0.,  10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  50.,  60.,  70.,  80.,  90., 100.,
        110., 120., 130., 140., 150., 160., 170., 180.]))
```

This runs in 2.7ms on my Mac using your supplied (515, 561, 3) image. I presume you could use multiprocessing to round-robin frames across multiple cores.

```
In [71]: %timeit process(im)
2.79 ms ± 64.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```