# How can I reduce colors of an image so it would have an exact number of colors?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image with a histogram that look like this:
[image]

I want the image to have only 10 different colors, how can I do that? (in other words I want the histogram to only have 10 values).

Comment: I suggest you add a language tag as well. Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49715101/7328782

Comment: Is this a grayscale image?  If it is, can we assume that the 10 grayscale values you want to represent your image with correspond to the mode / peak of each "mountain" in your histogram?

Comment: clustering combined with dithering.

Comment: check out the [K-Means](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html) algorithm, which clusters data into K groups.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you a) shared your image, b) showed your expected result and c) shared your latest/greatest code...

Comment: @stateMachine: there is a big risk that K-means will fail to find the correct clusters, though the gray ranges are obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookup table that associates [0,11] to 0, [12,35] to 23, [26,58] to 46... and [219, 255] to 230.

Comment: As always, a quality, robust suggestion.