# How to vectorize an image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Is there a way to convert an image into a vectorized form such as as follows:

I have looked this up searching for CNN, Pillow and CV2 methods however I didn't find any available resource online to implement this image transformation.

Appreciating your help on this matter.

Normal Image:

[image]

Vectorized Image:

[image]

Update:

I have implemented image segmentation using SLIC method, the following is new code and Resultant Image.
As can be seen, the new image is close to the vectorized image(desired outcome) however the quality/detail difference is still alot.

Any further ideas?

```
from skimage import data, segmentation, color
from skimage.future import graph
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io

path='/home/user/Desktop/Image1.jpeg'
img = io.imread(path)

labels1 = segmentation.slic(img, compactness=50, n_segments=5000,
                        start_label=1)
out1 = color.label2rgb(labels1, img, kind='avg', bg_label=0)
out1 = Image.fromarray(out1, 'RGB')
out1.save('/home/user/Desktop/1.png')
g = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels1, mode='similarity')
labels2 = graph.cut_normalized(labels1, g)
out2 = color.label2rgb(labels2, img, kind='avg', bg_label=0)
out2 = Image.fromarray(out2, 'RGB')
out2.save('/home/user/Desktop/2.png')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(6, 8))

ax[0].imshow(out1)
ax[1].imshow(out2)

for a in ax:
    a.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

New Image(N_Segments=2000)

[image]

New Image (N_segments=5000, took   5 minutes of computational time)
[image]

Comment: requires no AI. requires clustering of colors to form a palette (and apparently some smoothing). then you can vectorize using whatever algorithms exist for that.

Comment: Thanks, is there a resource/worked example on this you can recommend?

Comment: I wouldn't know, I didn't google that. -- you could probably *script* inkscape to do this for you

Comment: As a first step, you must segment the image, i.e. decompose it in areas of (relatively) constant color. Read this: https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/image-segmentation-in-python-opencv/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast color quantization in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710006/fast-color-quantization-in-opencv)

Comment: Hi, color quantization reduce the coloring of an image, its useful but doesn't specifically achieve the required

Comment: I have added an update to the original post, please have a look. thanks!

Comment: It is unclear to me what sort of a result you are expecting. I understand images to be characterised as *"bitmap"*, a.k.a. *"raster"*, or *"vectorised"* where the latter typically have SVG (or EPS) format, yet you show a bitmapped PNG image as your result. What do you actually want as a result please? What are you trying to do really?

Comment: I'am trying to get a vectorized image similar to the 2nd picture in the original post. That image was generated using vectormagic.com, iam trying to see how i can generate same style (as 2nd image) with python.

Comment: For those interest in the solution, I've used the vtracer module from github. Link as follows: https://github.com/visioncortex/vtracer. It's a command line utility, settings can be adjustment to achieve desired outcome.

Comment: IT HAS AN MIT LICENSE INSTEAD OF GPL (POTRACE'S LICENSE)!!!!!

Comment: Brohh, I was about to create a question to ask stack overflow community, ¿ how can I vectorize an image using python? and your question is answering mine, upvote for that! you are awesome! Thanks

Comment: No worries. Glad its useful.